# Invalid signature error in the jwt token and the token's date does not expire

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

When the token is generated and I try it, it gives an invalid signature error and its expiration date does not work.

```c#
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constansts.JWT_SECURITY_KEY_FOR_TOKEN)),
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        RequireSignedTokens = true
    };
});
```

```c#
 namespace SadAbNiroo
    {
        public class JWTAuthorizationManager
        {
            private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;         
    
            public JWTAuthorizationManager(UserManager<User> _userManager)
            {
                this._userManager = _userManager;
            }
            public async Task<JwtFeildsDto> Authenticate(string UserName, string PasswordHash)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(UserName);
                    //پیدا کردن همه نقش های کاربر
    
                var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                //ایجاد تاریخ انقضای توکن
                var tokenExpireTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Constansts.JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRE_TIME);
                //ایجاد متغیر از کلاس مشخص شده برای ایجاد توکن و اطلاعات همراه آن
                var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                //ایجاد آرایه ای از بایت ها به عنوان کلید توکن
                var tokenKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constansts.JWT_SECURITY_KEY_FOR_TOKEN);
                //از این کلاس برای نگهداری ویژگیها و اطلاعات درون توکن استفاده می شود.
                var List = new List<Claim>()
                    {
                        //new Claim("username", UserName),
                        new Claim("userId", user.Id),
    
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimaryGroupSid,"User Group 01")
    
                    };
    
    
                var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
        
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(List),
    
                    Expires = tokenExpireTimeStamp,
    
                    //امضا یا اعتبارنامه یا مجوز ورود
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey),SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };
    
    
    
                var securityToken = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
                var token = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
         
    
                    return new JwtFeildsDto
                    {
                        token = token,
                      
                        expire_time = (int)tokenExpireTimeStamp.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds
    
                    };
            }
        }
    }
```

```c#
   [Authorize(Policy = "UserPolicy")]
        [Route("~/api/v{version:apiVersion}/[action]")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Cachments(CancellationToken CT)
        {
            return Ok(await _cachments.FindAll(CT));
        }
```

```c#
public class UserPolicy : AuthorizationHandler<UserPolicyRequirement>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

        public UserPolicy(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this._contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }


        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserPolicyRequirement requirement)
        {
            var request = _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request;
            string actionName = request.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
            string controllerName = request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString();

            if (token != "")
            {
                var t = handler.ReadJwtToken(token.Replace("Bearer ", "")) as JwtSecurityToken;

                var userId = t.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "userId").Value;

                if (dbContext.userAccessActions.Any(a => a.UserId == userId && a.ActionName == actionName && a.ControllName == controllerName))
               
                    // اگر کاربر لاگین شده به اکشن مورد نظر دسترسی داشت.

                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                    else
                        //اگر دسترسی نداشت
                        context.Fail();
              
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you pls show the token? *invalid signature* - If you use the same key for signing and verification, there should be no problem. Did you get the inavlid signature error in your program or on jwt.io?

Comment: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJlNjNhODFlYi1lOTdiLTQ1NWYtOTk1ZC0xNjU2Zjg2MjM0YTQiLCJuYmYiOjE2ODI3NjAyMzYsImV4cCI6MTY4Mjc2MDgzNiwiaWF0IjoxNjgyNzYwMjM2fQ.8DSR6nYwb9q0OnuU0FisfyBEEh-MKNEotSLfRwcSjzM

Comment: And its expiration time doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code but didn't encounter your problem, the token expiration time is also working normally.

Have you checked your token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to see if there is any problem?
[image]

Put the value of `Constansts.JWT_SECURITY_KEY_FOR_TOKEN` into `VERIFY SIGNATURE` for verification to see if there is a problem.

If there is no problem, you can only debug step by step to see if your token has changed somewhere.

**Update:**

The problem should lie in your judgment on `dbContext.userAccessActions`. If I use the line below, it works:

```
var userId = t.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "userId").Value;

if (!context.User.HasClaim(x => x.Type == "userId"))
    return Task.CompletedTask;
context.Succeed(requirement);
```

Comment: Hi, I generated the token and it works normally, it means [Authorize] and it expires, but when the class

I wrote that I use [Authorize(Policy = "UserPolicy")], the token does not expire, and when I manipulate PAYLOAD, it gives an exception error.

Comment: Hi @sadegh, I update my answer, please check it. And please check whether your `dbContext.userAccessActions` can be used as a basis for judgment.

Comment: Hi @sadegh, did this answer can help you?